# how to manipulate in the string numbers in R?

Tags: r, string, insert, numbers, space

My data is a string of numbers pulled into R using read.table. Here is the data:

```
20402000224222032203233430020222024422320202234232443443004440404332402220404233302004204202004033420200022204334434044422322400200244044322202200234200424402002224303430023432202220343420323200300022320004223040024342244424040322424340240044220302432400203033300042423340222323200020034043004
```

I insert a space between each number, so the output looks more like this:

```
2 0 4 0 2 0 0 0..
```

I used:

```
exm <- read.csv("string.csv")
txt<- trimws(gsub("", " ", exm))
write.csv(txt, file= "new.csv")
```

This only inserts a space between numbers. I like to manipulate numbers separately. I do not like to be string numbers. I like to paste each number to one cell of excel.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're after. strsplit allows you to parse one long string with a shorter string, or in this case an empty string, and returns the results as a list.

```
longAssNumber <- "20402000224222032203233430020222024422320202234232443443004440404332402220404233302004204202004033420200022204334434044422322400200244044322202200234200424402002224303430023432202220343420323200300022320004223040024342244424040322424340240044220302432400203033300042423340222323200020034043004"

numberVector <- as.numeric(strsplit(longAssNumber, "")[[1]])

write.csv(numberVector, "number.csv")
```

Comment: Thank you very much. but result in the write.csv(numberVector, "number.csv") is:                                                                                Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 143, 9997.

Comment: I don't get that error. Can you amend your post with the exact code you executed please?

Comment: Thank you so much. I had a mistake in my file. Your code help to do my work.